# Rust "random access" iterator

Tags: rust, iterator

I would like to write an iterator for objects that implement a trait that allows accessing items by index. Something like this:

```
trait Collection {
    fn get_item(&self, index: usize) -> &Item;
    fn get_item_mut(&mut self, index: usize) -> &mut Item;
}
```

I know how to implement `next()` function for both `Iter` and `IterMut`. My question is which other `Iterator` methods do I need to implement to make the iterators as efficient as possible. What I mean by this is that for example `nth()` goes directly to the item, not calling `next()` until it reaches it. I'd like to know the minimum amount of functions I need to implement to make it work as fast as a slice iterator.

I've googled about this but can't find anything concrete on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On nightly, you can implement [`advance_by()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.advance_by). This will give you an efficient `nth()` for free, as well as other code that uses it in the standard library.

On stable, you need to implement `nth()`. And of course, `ExactSizeIterator` and `size_hint()`. For extra bit of performance you can also implement [`TrustedLen`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.TrustedLen.html) on nightly, allowing e.g. `collect::<Vec<_>>()` to take advantage of the fact that the amount of items yielded is guaranteed.

Unfortunately, you can never be as efficient as slice iterators, because they implement various std-private traits (e.g. `TrustedRandomAccess`) and libstd uses those traits with various specializations to make them more efficient in various situations.